# Need to fadeIn a webpage's entire contents on load but tiled bg pattern keeps doing the opposite

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, fadein, fadeout

I have a webpage with a tiled background body image. It needs to be tiled because the designer wants it scalable with the browser window. It creates a very specific grid over which the rest of the site is designed.

There is also a white page border around it (created via a separate div with a higher z-index) because the designer wants to keep the pattern away from the sides of the browser.

I need to fade the following page in it's entirety. When I try to fade in the body the screen starts with the pattern already there. And while playing around I've also managed to get the background to fades in but then everything else fades out. I have also tried placing the bg pattern in a div just below the body, but it seems to do strange things in Safari.

I have also tried the following tutorial, but to no avail:

http://blog.anselmbradford.com/2009/08/28/how-to-add-a-simple-webpage-fade-in-effect-using-jquery/

My thought then is to somehow build a white div overlaying everything, then fading that out. But how do I make this div cover everything, including the body background image?

I feel like I'm missing something big here...

Here is the relevant code I'm working with:

HTML:

```
<body id="home">

<div id="pgborder"></div><!-- end #pgborder-->

<div id="main">

<ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="us.html">us</a></li>
      <li><a href="work.html">work</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div><!-- end #main--> 

<div id="logo">

  <a href="home.html"><img src="images/logo.gif" width="345" height="24" alt="manuchugh logo"/></a>

</div><!-- end #logo-->

</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "century gothic", arial, sans serif;
  color: #8c8d8d;
  font-size: 15px; 
  overflow: auto;
  background:#fff url('../images/bg.gif');
  }

#pgborder {
  border: 22px #fff solid;  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine it not fading because you're applying the background image to the `html` as well.

Try removing the following line from `html, body {`

```
background:#fff url('../images/bg.gif');
```

and placing it with a `body` selector in the CSS:

```
body {
    background:#fff url('../images/bg.gif');
}
```